# InvalidArgumentError on Decoder Model during Inference, for LSTM-based Seq2Seq on Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, lstm, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, seq2seq

> **versions**: Python 3.6.9, Tensorflow 2.0.0, CUDA 10.0, CUDNN 7.6.1, Nvidia driver version 410.78.

I'm trying to port a LSTM-based Seq2Seq tf.keras model to tensorflow 2.0

Right now I'm facing the following error when I try to call `predict` on the decoder model (see below for the actual inference setup code)

It is as if it were expecting a **single word as argument**, but I need it to decode a full sentence (my sentences are right-padded sequences of word indices, of length 24)

> **P.S.:** This code used to work **exactly as it is** on TF 1.15

```
InvalidArgumentError:  [_Derived_]  Inputs to operation while/body/_1/Select_2 of type Select must have the same size and shape.
Input 0: [1,100] != input 1: [24,100]
     [[{{node while/body/_1/Select_2}}]]
     [[lstm_1_3/StatefulPartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_45160]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph -> keras_scratch_graph -> keras_scratch_graph
```

**FULL MODEL**

[image]

**ENCODER inference model**

[image]

**DECODER inference model**

[image]

### Inference Setup (line where error actually happens)

Important information: sequences are right-padded to **24** elements and **100** is the number of dimensions for each word embedding. This is why the error message (and the prints) show that the input shapes are `(24,100)`.

> note that this code runs on a **CPU**. running it on a GPU leads to another error detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895694/cudnn-status-bad-param-when-trying-to-perform-inference-on-a-lstm-seq2seq-with-m)

```py
# original_keyword is a sample text string

with tf.device("/device:CPU:0"):

    # this method turns the raw string into a right-padded sequence
    query_sequence = keyword_to_padded_sequence_single(original_keyword)

    # no problems here
    initial_state = encoder_model.predict(query_sequence)

    print(initial_state[0].shape) # prints (24, 100)
    print(initial_state[1].shape) # (24, 100)

    empty_target_sequence = np.zeros((1,1))

    empty_target_sequence[0,0] = word_dict_titles["sos"]

    # ERROR HAPPENS HERE:
    # InvalidArgumentError:  [_Derived_]  Inputs to operation while/body/_1/Select_2 of type Select 
    # must have the same size and shape.  Input 0: [1,100] != input 1: [24,100]
    decoder_outputs, h, c = decoder_model.predict([empty_target_sequence] + initial_state)
```

**Things I have tried**

- disabling eager mode (this just made training much slower and the error during inference stayed the same)
- reshaping the input prior to feeding it to the predict function
- manually computing (`embedding_layer.compute_mask(inputs)`) and setting masks when calling the LSTM layers

Comment: How do you build your layers? Did you set return_sequences=True in your LSTM layer?

Comment: @emirc for the encoder it's `False`. For the decoder, it's `True`. Here's the full code: https://gist.github.com/queirozfcom/20d76e3113c649660df8dc1e59455680

Comment: Hi, can you try to change the `decoder_inputs` shape to `decoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,),name="decoder_input")`.  The error is coming because `empty_target_sequence` has a shape `(1,1)` while your decoder expects an input of shape `(?,24)`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see from your model architecture, the `initial_state` is an array of tensors with shapes: `[(?, 100), (?, 100), (?, 100)]`. In your case the unknown dimension is fixed to 24.

Then, you build a Numpy array/TF tensor of shape `(1, 1)`. You wrap it inside a list and append your `initial_state`. Hence you get a list of tensors with shapes: `[(1, 1), (?, 100), (?, 100), (?, 100)]`.

You try to pass it as an input to your decoder model which expect 3 inputs (a list of inputs) with shapes `[(?, 24), (?, 100), (?, 100)]`.

Starting from that it seems there is something wrong...

However, TF complains about the inputs of the operation `while/body/_1/Select_2`. The `input 1` should come from any of your `initial_state` tensor (which we know has a shape `(24, 100)`). The `input 2` seems to come from your `empty_target_sequence` that has a shape `(1, 1)` which can be [broadcasted](https://databricks.com/tensorflow/dimensionality-and-broadcasting) to `(1, 100)`. By the way, it is strange that it is not broadcasted to `(24, 100)` as both dimensions are of size 1...

I would recommend to check your graph in TensorBoard. You should be able to find the messy operation and track its input tensors.